# Identity crisis. What exactly am I?

Tags: riddle

Application of the mind is where I begin
Depictions of what is, what was, will be, and perhaps have never been
Vibrant color with each  illustrious stroke one will strive 
Unlimited potential for an imagination that is now alive

In the middle there is only me, this you knew 
My neighbors make up two thirds of you

As we come to the end we reach an uncomfortable state 
Perhaps because of something off your plate 
Gagging, heaving, flailing violently in attempts to mitigate  
Always remember how essential it is to masticate

Comment: Are you a ..............."Neck" ?

Comment: Deleting those newlines makes a *huge* difference in the way the riddle reads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might you be

> an artichoke

?

Reason:

One:

> You begin with "art"

Two:

> In the middle, you have "I" having neighbors "O" and "U" as [someone else pointed out](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/4594/5421)

Three:

> In the end, you "choke" because you failed to masticate properly

Comment: bingooooooooooo

Answer (score 4):

I think it's:

> The palate

My reasoning:

Application of the mind is where I begin
Depictions of what is, what was, will be, and perhaps have never been

> *Palate* can refer to someone's tastes, opinions, thoughts, etc. regarding appreciation of aesthetics.

Vibrant color with each illustrious stroke one will strive
Unlimited potential for an imagination that is now alive

> A *palate* is what an artist uses to hold and mix different colors of paint while painting.

In the middle there is only me, this you knew
My neighbors make up two thirds of you

> The *palate* is the middle, top part of your mouth. "Neighbors" could refer to teeth and tongue (bone and muscle, two thirds of the components of the mouth, with the remainder being soft tissue such as gums and palate) or to nose and mouth (both adjacent to the palate, and two of the three facial cavities, the third being the eyes).

As we come to the end we reach an uncomfortable state
Perhaps because of something off your plate

Gagging, heaving, flailing violently in attempts to mitigate
Always remember how essential it is to masticate

> If you don't chew properly, food can get lodged in your palate and you can choke to death.

Comment: wonderful answer. Though not quite what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

> A Dilemma
>  its a decision that needs to be made which conjures all possible routes taken
>  colours would be the emotions the decision in each route will cause
>  em reverse is me which is the middle whilst the neighbours DIL MA, well ma is 2/3 of man
>  The decision made can be uncomfortable
>  choking on the decision, its good the chew the fat?